# input stop default aligning if text too long for input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input field which has a max length of 4 characters. It looks as if those 4 characters are separated by a border which actually are 3 lines that are displayed above the input field.

If I enter the fourth characters all the characters are jumping a little bit to the left because a potential fifth character wouldn't be seen if it was entered. If the focus is not on the input field the characters are nicely aligned as I want them to be.

Is there a way to fix this issue with css, js or jquery or this is behaviour from the browser which can't be altered?

```css
.pin-field-wrapper {
  width: 175px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 0px 13px 13px 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.pin-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 13px 13px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 44px;
  letter-spacing: 21px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96);
}

.pin-field-separator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: text;
}

.separator1 {
  left: 25%;
}

.separator2 {
  left: 50%;
}

.separator3 {
  left: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin-field-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="pin-field" placeholder="0000" maxlength="4">
  <div class="pin-field-separator separator1"></div>
  <div class="pin-field-separator separator2"></div>
  <div class="pin-field-separator separator3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible, could you give us an example of what you're trying to achieve, as it's possible there's a better method than you're currently using.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated the snippet. If you now enter 4 characters you'll see everyting jumps a little to the lift

Answer (score 0):

Your font size doesn't match the width of `input` field. Just make it wider or reduce the font size.

```css
.pin-field-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 72px;
  border-radius: 0px 13px 13px 0px;
  border-left: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.pin-field {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 13px 13px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 44px;
  letter-spacing: 21px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 6px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96);
}

.pin-field-separator {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  top: 0px;
  cursor: text;
}

.separator1 {
  left: 20%;
}

.separator2 {
  left: 44%;
}

.separator3 {
  left: 69%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin-field-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="pin-field" placeholder="0000" maxlength="4">
  <div class="pin-field-separator separator1"></div>
  <div class="pin-field-separator separator2"></div>
  <div class="pin-field-separator separator3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But than the format doesn't fit. The numbers aren't equally divided. Isn't there a workaround for this?

Comment: @user3398922 I updated my answer changing separators' positions. Just try to find the sweat spot and it will work. If you want another solution then just use 4 inputs and use JavaScript to change focus allowing user to use them as a single input.